# Limit scope of rule defined inside namespace

Tags: ruby, rake

I have the following Rakefile (this is a simplified example):

```
namespace :green do
  rule(/^build:/) do |t|
    puts "[green] #{t}"
  end

  task :start do
    puts '[green] start'
  end

  task run: ['build:app', :start]
end

namespace :blue do
  rule(/^build:/) do |t|
    puts "[blue] #{t}"
  end

  task :start do
    puts '[blue] start'
  end

  task run: ['build:app', :start]
end
```

I would like each "build" rule to apply only within the namespace where it's defined.  In other words, this is what I *want* to happen:

```
$ rake blue:run
[blue] build:app
[blue] start
```

But what actually happens is this (with Rake 12.3.1):

```
$ rake blue:run
[green] build:app
[blue] start
```

Is there a way to limit the scope of the "build" rules so that the rule defined in the "green" namespace isn't accessible from the "blue" namespace?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Rake doesn't support this natively.  Tasks are scoped to the namespace they are defined in (by adding the scope path as a prefix), but rules get no such prefix.

I was able to get this to work by monkey-patching Rake, which is not ideal:

```
# Monkey-patch rake
module Rake
  module TaskManager
    # Copied from rake 12.3.1 and enhanced for scoped rules
    def lookup_in_scope(name, scope)
      loop do
        tn = scope.path_with_task_name(name)
        task = @tasks[tn]
        return task if task
        break if scope.empty?
        # BEGIN ADDED LINES
        task = enhance_with_matching_rule(tn)
        return task if task
        # END ADDED LINES
        scope = scope.tail
      end
      nil
    end
  end

  module DSL
    # Create a rule inside a namespace scope
    def scoped_rule(name, &block)
      pattern = "^#{Rake.application.current_scope.path}:#{name}:"
      Rake.application.create_rule(Regexp.new(pattern), &block)
    end
  end
end

namespace :green do
  scoped_rule :build do |t|
    puts t
  end

  task :start do |t|
    puts t
  end

  task run: ['build:app', :start]
end

namespace :blue do
  scoped_rule :build do |t|
    puts t
  end

  task :start do |t|
    puts t
  end

  task run: ['build:app', :start]
end
```

Output:

```
$ rake green:run
green:build:app
green:start
$ rake blue:run
blue:build:app
blue:start
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's not the best solution, but I think it maybe can help you.

```
rule(/^build*/) do |t|
  Rake::Task["green:build"].invoke if ARGV[0].start_with? "green"
  Rake::Task["blue:build"].invoke if ARGV[0].start_with? "blue"
end

namespace :green do
  task :build do
    puts '[green] build'
  end

  task :start do
    puts '[green] start'
  end

  task run: ['build.app', :start]
end

namespace :blue do
  task :build do
    puts '[blue] build'
  end

  task :start do
    puts '[blue] start'
  end

  task run: ['build.app', :start]
end
```

Testing it we have:

```
rake green:run # [green] build
               # [green] start

rake blue:run # [blue] build
              # [blue] start
```

Comment: $ rake blue:run
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'build.app' (see --tasks)

Tasks: TOP => blue:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: I'm sorry. My copy and paste weren't working, so I had rewritten all the code again and I missed a character. I edited the code now, and I'm pretty sure it's gonna work this time.

Comment: Okay, this doesn't really answer the question though.  The question asked for "a way to limit the scope of the 'build' rules" but in your example, "blue:build" is not rule at all, only a task.  As a result, it prints only "[blue] build" and not "[blue] build:app".

Comment: In other words, the top-level "build" rule in your example doesn't serve any useful purpose, because you could accomplish the same result by depending on the scoped "build" tasks directly.